# How to Check SMTP server of Recieved Emails

Tags: smtp

I am using [Interspire email marketer](https://www.interspire.com/emailmarketer/) to send emails.

And I am using Mail Server Details to use my own SMTP server. For example mail.mymailserver.com in order to send the emails while my original server is something like
www.myserver.com.

All I need is to check if mails are being sent from mail.mymailserver.com but in the headers of the emails I can see is ip and mail server of mail.myserver.com.

Is there any way I check this please?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the receiving mail server will add a `Received:` header with IP and/or address of sending mail server.  Be sure to send your test mail to some third party (that is, not to yourself at myserver.com).